# Passing a servlet variable into javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, variables, servlets

I'm looking to pass a servlet variable, myVar that is passed into a JSP page, and pass it to  JavaScript. The JavaScript is an external javascript that is included into the JSP page.

I have a button that calls the JavaScript function, but I'm unable to pass any of the variables that are passed into the JSP page through the servlet. The button is not a part of a form.

I've tried in a function in JavaScript to call:

```
var x = '<%=myVar%>';
```

AND

```
var x = '${myVar}';
```

AND

```
var x = '<%= (String)request.getParameter("myVar") %>';
```

However, `x` is always a string of what I inputted.

I'm not using AJAX or JQuery. Any ideas?

Example Code is a simplified version: (so the button is actually a drop down that calls the js when I change the value, however, I want other variables that are not part of the drop down to be called in changeCLass)

Servlet side:

```
request.setAttribute("otherVars","tests");
```

JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>

<select name="vars" id="myVars" onchange="changeClass(this)">
<option value='1' selected="selected">1</option>
</select>
```

external.js included in JSP:

```
function changeClass(newVarX) {

    var newVarId =newVarX.value;
    var tID = '${otherVars}';

    alert(newVarId + " " + tID);
}
```

Output:
1 $(otherVars}

but output should be:
1 tests

Comment: is this code taken from the external file?

Comment: @user1798546 simple way of doing it is creating a hidden field that stores the value and getting it from there. Another way is to pass the variable into the js function as a parameter
`<button onclick='someFunction(<%= (String)request.getParameter("myVar") %>)'> Call function</button>`

Comment: It would be better to explain how your application behaves atm (with code sample) to have a better understanding and provide a better solution

Comment: "The JavaScript is an external javascript that is included into the JSP page" - could you post the JSP showing how you include this file?

Comment: BTW ${otherVars} won't work on its own- you'll need to use c:out or a similar tag eg <c:out value="${otherVars}"/>

Comment: Jan's answer below highlights your problem - external.js is included in the page by the browser client-side and so isn't processed as JSP on the server.

Answer (score 3):

This does not work, because your JavaScript file is not processed by the server. Possible solutions are:

- Declare the variable `tID` globally in the JSP file.

  JSP:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var tID = '${otherVars}';
  </script>

  <select name="vars" id="myVars" onchange="changeClass(this)">
      <option value='1' selected="selected">1</option>
  </select>
  ```

  JavaScript (external.js):

  ```
  function changeClass(newVarX) {
      var newVarId = newVarX.value;
      alert(newVarId + " " + tID);
  }
  ```
- Have the JavaScript file also be processed. You may use a JSP file for the JavaScript and apply the correct content type:

  JSP:

  ```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="external.jsp"></script>

  <select name="vars" id="myVars" onchange="changeClass(this)">
      <option value='1' selected="selected">1</option>
  </select>
  ```

  JavaScript (external.jsp --> note, that it's a JSP file, too, but the content type is set to text/javascript):

  ```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  function changeClass(newVarX) {
      var newVarId = newVarX.value;
      var tID = '${otherVars}';
      alert(newVarId + " " + tID);
  }
  ```

Comment: Just edited the answer. In the second solution the JavaScript file is a JSP file, but the content type is set to text/javascript. This will make the server process the file, so Java code can be used.