# Passing variables from server to client side

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

Should only an inline Javascript be used in a JSP to set variables with values of server side variables ??

For eg: Inside JSP here's the inline JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Do something inline with variable from server.
    var variableFromServer = 'variableFromServer';
    doSomethingInline(variableFromServer);
    function doSomethingInline(variable) {
        alert('doSomethingInline: ' + variable);
    }

    // Do something onload with variable from server.
    function doSomethingOnload(variable) {
        alert('doSomethingOnload: ' + variable);
    }
</script>
```

Here,
Can't i put this code in a .js file and include the js file in my JSP and still access a server variable ?? Will it work only with inline js?

Comment: Where is the variable? I only see hard-coded string constants in your example.

Comment: I meant something like this:var clearanceRequestType = '<s:property value="clearanceRequest.clearanceRequestType"/>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a server side variable from an external js file that is simply referenced from your jsp page. The reason is that the jsp code is processed at the server side, while the referenced external js will be included and processed at the client side by the browser.

However it is possible to declare your external js file as jsp and included in your jsp so that it is processed at server side and become inline js at client side .

Another approach is to create global js variables and then use these from the external referenced js files.

Check out the following thread you'll find examples,
[Passing a servlet variable into javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222034/passing-a-servlet-variable-into-javascript)